# Update with cursor not iterate in feed data

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my update query with cursor. but it update all records of  `COM_Customer` with first record in `#TempTable` and not iterate in `#TempTable`

```
DECLARE @CustomerNumber VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT CustomerNumber 
    FROM #TempTable

OPEN db_cursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CustomerNumber   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    PRINT @CustomerNumber

    UPDATE COM_Customer
    SET CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber
    WHERE CustomerNumber IS NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CustomerNumber   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Is it completely arbitrary which rows from the temp table get assigned? There seems to be no correlation or ordering involved

Comment: Have you considered what happens if your temp table has fewer rows than those in the updated table where the column is null? After your "answer", there will still be null values in your table. Is that your goal?

Answer (score 1):

> but it update all records of COM_Customer with first record in
> #TempTable and not iterate in #TempTable

The query does iterate `#TempTable`. The `PRINT @CustomerNumber` will print out each value from `#TempTable`

The reason that it updates all with first value from `#TempTable` is because, the `UPDATE` query does exactly what it is supposed to do. It updates all rows with `CustomerNumber IS NULL`. So subsequent iteration does not have any rows with `CustomerNumber IS NULL`

```
UPDATE COM_Customer
SET    CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber
WHERE  CustomerNumber IS NULL
```

---

Seems like you are updating arbitrary rows from `#TempTable` to `COM_Customer`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a sequence and used that to `JOIN` both tables. And without cursor at all.

```
UPDATE C
SET    CustomerNumber = T.CustomerNumber
FROM   (
            SELECT CustomerNumber, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerNumber)
            FROM   COM_Customer
            WHERE  CustomerNumber IS NULL
       ) C
       INNER JOIN
       (
            SELECT CustomerNumber, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerNumber)
            FROM   #TempTable
       ) T ON C.RN = T.RN
```

Comment: You should point out (or did you miss it) that your first derived table C will have row numbers generated in an undefined order (because CustomerNumber is NULL for all selected rows).

Answer (score -1):

Resolved:

```
DECLARE @CustomerNumber VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT CustomerNumber FROM #TempTable
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CustomerNumber   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       PRINT @CustomerNumber
   SET ROWCOUNT 1 --added
   Update COM_Customer
   set CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber
   where CustomerNumber is null
   SET ROWCOUNT  0 --added
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CustomerNumber   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: An answer should contain a description of what was changed in addition to working code.